# Workflow rule to stop field update

Tags: workflow

Scenario is if field contain a value and you want to update then the value of that field is not update. else if field is null then that field is to be updated.

To full fill that condition i create a workflow rule :

Screenshot below:[image]

[image]

> Right now when field is not null then it work properly but when i
>   delete the data from field and field become null then that flow also
>   triggered and not updating the field. Can someone please help me out..

Comment: In layman's term you never want, PCL_CashToClose__c as null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement

1. We can create a record having `PCL_CashToClose__c` as null
2. Later stages, we can assign a values to `PCL_CashToClose__c`
3. If someone tries to clear the values , the system should not allow it

The current way, you are trying to do will result as, a user clears value of `PCL_CashToClose__c` and saves, and bam they see that value, which would confuse them or might make them think its system's bug.

A better approach would be to show them an informative error message that, you cannot blank out PCL_CashToClose__c field once the value is set.

This is ideal candidate for Validation Rule:

```
ISBLANK( PCL_CashToClose__c ) && 
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(PCL_CashToClose__c )))
```

Validation Message: Cash To Close once set cannot be made as blank.